# NpgSQL column names converting to lower-case even when double-quoted in text

Tags: c#, npgsql

I'm writing a C# UI against a Postgres DB I do not control (and utilizing Npgsql 4.0.6 to do so); the DB was created with camelcase object names, so it's necessary to escape them with double quotes. In other programming languages, and when even defining DataSet objects in the VS GUI, this is a piece of cake.

But when I manually assign a CommandText to a NpgsqlCommand and then do something like a NpgsqlDataAdapter based on that command, any double quotes put around the column names are ignored and the columns are automatically switched to lower-case (which cases the query to fail). To add insult to injury, the Hint in the resulting exception asks if I meant to use the correctly capitalized column name, which of course I did. I've confirmed that the actual CommandText property of the command I'm running contains properly-escaped double quotes around all the columns -- but the driver seems to override or further transform this value before actually passing it to the DB.

The NpgSQL github page recommends that questions of this sort be posted to Slack Overflow for the fastest response, so I'm hoping that people have run into this one before and have a workaround that doesn't involve renaming all the objects in the DB.

I've tried escaping the double quotes in different ways, including the full table name, using table aliases, etc. In all cases, whenever I pass a SelectCommand into NpgsqlDataAdapter, any double quotes in the CommandText are just ignored when resolved by the driver. This does NOT occur if I set up a DataAdapter object in the Designer, but obviously that approach shouldn't always be necessary.

```
string strCommand = @"SELECT * FROM fs.""AppUsers""  WHERE ""UserID"" = @UserID;";
string strTable = "SelectedUserInfo";
using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.PostgresConnectionString))
{
    using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(strCommand, conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 3000;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
        cmd.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = _UserID;
        using (NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(ds, strTable);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM fs.\"AppUsers\"  WHERE \"AppUsers\".\"UserID\" = @UserID;"
ex.Message: 42703: "column \"userid\" does not exist"
ex.Hint: "Perhaps you meant to reference the column \"AppUsers.UserID\"."
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. I have created an AppUsers table and executed almost exactly the same code as above, and am seeing everything quoted properly. I'd double-check what's going on: it seems that in your sample the AppUsers table is properly quoted (no error), it's unlikely a bug exists which would only be doing this for the column name.

Comment: One more thought is to turn on SQL statement logging (either at the Npgsql side or in PostgreSQL) and to have a look at the actual SQL being sent by Npgsql to PostgreSQL.